# Flipping Transistors with Circuiktikz

Tags: scaling, circuitikz

I was wondering if there was any way to flip a transistor or similar node component around in the [`circuitikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) package? For the bipoles it's fairly simple as you just reverse the start and end, but for more advanced circuits I'm having trouble (things such as current mirrors or what have you). I've seen various solutions on scaling up and down, but none on flipping.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Would you please provide an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), that would make it easier for us to develop a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly what you mean by "flipping". If you are interested in getting reflections on the `x`, and `y` axes, then you can use `xscale=-1` and/or `yscale=-1` and provide the right anchors for the labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}%

\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) node[nmos,xscale=-1] (mos) {}
(mos.base) node[anchor=east] {B}
(mos.gate) node[anchor=west] {G}
(mos.drain) node[anchor=south] {D}
(mos.source) node[anchor=north] {S}
;
\draw (3,0) node[nmos] (mos) {}
(mos.base) node[anchor=west] {B}
(mos.gate) node[anchor=east] {G}
(mos.drain) node[anchor=south] {D}
(mos.source) node[anchor=north] {S}
;
\draw (6,0) node[nmos,yscale=-1] (mos) {}
(mos.base) node[anchor=west] {B}
(mos.gate) node[anchor=east] {G}
(mos.drain) node[anchor=north] {D}
(mos.source) node[anchor=south] {S}
;
\draw (9,0) node[nmos,xscale=-1,yscale=-1] (mos) {}
(mos.base) node[anchor=east] {B}
(mos.gate) node[anchor=west] {G}
(mos.drain) node[anchor=north] {D}
(mos.source) node[anchor=south] {S}
;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, that's perfect! I only tried `scale` not `xscale` or `yscale`

Comment: doesn't seem to work for Tnigfetd; it moves the position but doesn't flip the drawn transistor

Comment: use `invert` or `mirror` -- see latest circuitikz docs

Answer (score 1):

use `invert` or `mirror`, this is the most easy way to flip a component.

Comment: This seems to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could maybe add a MWE and make your post a bit more like an answer.

Comment: Tnx, currently I haven't enough reputation to comment or up vote a comment.

Comment: @Dictator But you have enough reputation to add complete code from `\documentclass` down to `\end{document}` to your answer. This would help a lot to understand your suggestion. See the other answer for an example, how to do it.